# Why isn't my C++ maximizing pairwise product code working?

Tags: c++, function, loops, if-statement, multiplication

So the problem asked me to find the greatest product from a given sequence of non-negative integers. What I did was I tried to find the greatest two integers from the sequence (for which I used a vector, by taking an input of n numbers) and multiplied them, since there are no negative integers. I used the long long type as well, since just an int type would not be enough for huge numbers. I kept getting a random huge number as the output whenever I tried to run the program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

long long max_prod(const vector<int>& numbers) {
    int max1 = -1;
    int max2 = -1;
    int n = numbers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        if (numbers[i] > numbers[max1]) 
            max1 = i;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (numbers[j] > numbers[max2] && j!=max1)
            max2 = j;
    }
return ((long long)(numbers[max1])) * ((long long)(numbers[max2]));
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> numbers(n);
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    long long result = max_prod(numbers);
    cout << result << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[the last line is the output given by the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwmuv.png)

Comment: `if (numbers[i] > numbers[max1]) `: you have set `max` to `-1`, so `numbers[max1]` is arbitrary junk.

Comment: Oh. I thought max[-1] would give the last element of the vector, because I think that's how it is in python. Thanks, I'll see if it works.

Comment: The uses of `-1` in this code are dangerous for several reasons.  Any vector with a size less than `2` is going to use index `-1` in the final answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My code works now that I changed them to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haver undefined behavior right here

```
long long max_prod(const vector<int>& numbers) {
    int max1 = -1; <<<<<====
    int max2 = -1;
    int n = numbers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > numbers[max1]) <<<<<==
            max1 = i;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (numbers[j] > numbers[max2] && j != max1)
            max2 = j;
    }
    return ((long long)(numbers[max1])) * ((long long)(numbers[max2]));
}
```

You try to access `numbers[-1]` (twice once in the j loop and once in the i loop).

Set maxi and maxj to 0

Comment: Thanks a lot! My code works now that I changed them to 0.